# How to add line break in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add the line break from javascript for this snippet

```
function getCity(city_name, product_cat){
  var writecity = document.createTextNode(city_name+','+product_cat);
  document.getElementById("order_list").appendChild(writecity,'<br>');
}
```

I am calling this function in for loop, but the values printed are all coming in the same line. but i want to add the break line after each value printed. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

[.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) takes only one argument, so the second string(`<br>`) passed to it is ignored.

You need to call `appendChild()` again to add the `br` element

```
function getCity(city_name, product_cat) {
    var writecity = document.createTextNode(city_name + ',' + product_cat);
    var el = document.getElementById("order_list");
    el.appendChild(writecity);
    el.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `document.createElement`:

```
document.getElementById("order_list").appendChild(writecity);
document.getElementById("order_list").appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
```

Answer (score 0):

appendChild only takes one argument, I think. So you'll have to append another child:

```
function getCity(city_name, product_cat){
   var writecity = document.createTextNode(city_name+','+product_cat);
   var break = document.createElement('br');
   document.getElementById("order_list").appendChild(writecity);
   document.getElementById("order_list").appendChild(break);
}
```